# Play songs in Spotify from code in terminal Python

Tags: python, spotify, remote-access, playback, spotipy

Hi everyone I'm seeing tutorials of Spotify API but I have one doubt, it's possible to send directly from code comands like play, next or play an specific song?

And if you are playing spotify in your phone it will change the song?

Update 1: This is the code that I have at the moment but I have this error message when I run it: **(HELP WITH THIS)**

```
SpotifyException: http status: 403, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play:
 Player command failed: Premium required, reason: PREMIUM_REQUIRED
```

And this is my code:

```
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import spotipy


client_id = ""
client_secret = ""
autor = 'Radiohead' 

sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id, client_secret))
result = sp.search(autor)
print(result)
#
sp.start_playback(uris=['spotify:artist:4Z8W4fKeB5YxbusRsdQVPb'])
```

Comment: I believe all you get from the spotify API via spotipy is the URL where the stream is located and so you will need a client that knows how to connect to that URL and interpret the stream. Perhaps using something like [spotify-cli](https://pypi.org/project/spotify-cli/) you can use `spotipy`, like in your example above, to search and get the URL and then pass it over to `spotify-cli` to play it (instead of a web browser).

Comment: I like your answer do you have an example?

Comment: [Here is](https://github.com/spotipy-dev/spotipy/blob/master/examples/player.py) a demo scrip of how you can control Spotify with Python. (It assumes you have set [environment variabels](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/master/))

Comment: “Player command failed: Premium required” means that `start_playback()` requires a Spotify Premium subscription. Alternatively, I've found [this](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/Basic-controls-via-command-line/m-p/4360856#M15590) and [this](https://blomsmail.medium.com/take-the-bus-how-to-control-spotify-with-the-terminal-43f7bd44aed1), but both require Linux / I don't know how to get it working on Windows.

Comment: @Ximzend actually I'm using colab and I have Premium Spotify

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it directly. That function can't be used with the `SpotifyClientCredentials()` manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
from pprint import pprint

client_id = ""
client_secret = ""
redirect_uri = ""
scope = "user-read-playback-state,user-modify-playback-state"

sp = spotipy.Spotify(
        auth_manager=spotipy.SpotifyOAuth(
          client_id=client_id,
          client_secret=client_secret,
          redirect_uri=redirect_uri,    
          scope=scope, open_browser=False))

# Shows playing devices
res = sp.devices()
pprint(res)

# Change track
sp.start_playback(uris=['spotify:track:6gdLoMygLsgktydTQ71b15'])
```

You have to put a dummy redirect URL inside the code and in the dashboard of your app.
The script will ask “Go to the following URL:”, and after logging in, you'll need copy the resulting URL after “Enter the URL you was redirected to:”.